# Highchart/stock returns different object when zooming

Tags: highcharts

In highstocks tooltip I need to show data of the specific point.

This is how I do that:

```
tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var s = '<b>'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) +'</b>';
                s += '<br/>Time: '+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%mu', this.x);

                if(this.point)
                {
                    s += "<br/>this is a flag on " + new Date(this.point.x).toDateString();
                }
                else
                {
                    s += '<br/>Price: '+ this.points[0].y +' EUR';
                    s += '<br/>Ask: '+ this.points[0].point.ask +' EUR';
                    s += '<br/>Bid: '+ this.points[0].point.bid +' EUR';
                    console.log(this.points[0].point);
                }

                return s;
            }

        },
```

When hovering over a point I get more info about that specific point.

```
s += '<br/>Price: '+ this.points[0].y +' EUR';
s += '<br/>Ask: '+ this.points[0].point.ask +' EUR';
s += '<br/>Bid: '+ this.points[0].point.bid +' EUR';
```

This goes well if my zoom(rangeselector) is set on YTD or lower.

The weird thing is when I set my zoom on 1y or All, `this.points[0].point.` is gone. I can  not find the ask and bid value that i've set.

I hope my explanation is clear.

Problem solved:

```
dataGrouping : {
    enabled: false
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it helped!

    dataGrouping : {
        enabled: false
    }

Comment: When using dataGrouping, Highstock will create points. So all extra info will be disbanded.

Answer (score 0):

I feel commited to answer this, as I overlooked this for a couple of hours trying to find the solution for a similar problem, even though it is answered as an edit in the question. So here is a solution:

```
series: [{
     name: 'USD to EUR',
     data: newusdeur,
     dataGrouping : {
          enabled: false
     }
}]
```

Alternative:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataGrouping : {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X9275/2/)

[API reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.spline.dataGrouping)